# Need to use taxonomy term as url argument to filter a view but the term is attached to a node ref field

Tags: 6, taxonomy-terms, nodes, views

Not sure if the title makes much sense so I'll try to explain what I'm trying to do a little more in detail.

I am building a scoreboard section of my site for high school football scores from around the state. My "score" node has two node reference fields, "home team" and "away team" that point to a "team" node. The "team" node has some taxonomy terms, namely "county" and "conference."

I am trying to build a view that lists all of the "score" nodes for the week. The main scoreboard is working, no problem. But I'd also like to be able to have links like "http://example.com/scoreboard/county-name" and "http://example.com/scoreboard/conference-name" that would just show the scores for the schools in the respective county or conference.

The following is a screenshot of how my relationships, arguments, and fields are set up.

[image: screenshot]

The following is a screenshot of how the view displays on the "/scoreboard" page.

[image: screenshot]

But, if I try to go to "http://example.com/scoreboard/hamilton" I get a blank page. Am I missing something simple here? It seems like it should be possible but I'm not getting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure the *Taxonomy: Term* argument to use one of the relationships that you have set up. I do not know why you have an additional *Node: Nid* argument. According to your description, it is not necessary. Remove it unless you have some other requirement that makes this argument necessary.

Setting up the view in a way that does not match the requirements should not result in a blank page. The usual techniques for debugging PHP applications can be applied to figure out what went wrong: Printing out variable values or (if you have Xdebug or the like installed) step-by-step execution.

Comment: I should clarify. When I say blank page I don't mean the dreaded white page. Just blank where the scoreboard data should be.

Comment: Also, adding another Term argument and then setting up the relationships on them did the trick. I overlooked that because I had set up the argument before creating the relationships. Thanks!